# Python: Finding the length of a float with zeros at the end

Tags: python

I have several float values that have necessary zeros at the ends.

One number that I have is `0.0013790`.

When finding the length of this, I get `8` when I should be getting `9`, since the zero at the end is dropped. I can not use `.format()`, since some numbers are shorter than others and there is no concrete length that I want them set to. If I had a `float` that was seven digits long after the decimal and set the format to `8`, I would get an extra zero which should NOT belong there.

I can not afford to have my program adding zeros through format when they are not always necessary, since some numbers will be shorter than others. How do I find the actual length of these numbers when a zero is at the end?

I can not make an if statement that checks if the number `.endswith 0`, because it never does. The zero is always dropped! I am already checking the length of the string of the float and still the zero is dropped! Many numbers will not end with zero, so I can not simply add one to the length found. Please help!

**Numbers to test:**
When inputting _, you should get _. If you can get the below to work along with some other numbers, please give me the solution. I've been racking at my brain for hours!! Thanks.

WANTED RESULTS: `0.12345 -> 7, 0.123450 -> 8, 0.1234500 -> 9`.

UPDATE:
Thank you for your solutions, but the numbers are not inputs. I have them set to the eval() function, since I have roughly 1000 variables that need to be accessed dynamically from a websocket. Values are retrieved just fine, but if I am not mistaken, eval() defaults to float. Switching it from float to string has not done me much good, since I am guessing that eval() is always a float. Any solutions??

Comment: Can you reformulate that question in a more concise statement? It is really long.

Comment: `float` objects do not have a "length", so it is very unclear what you mean. You should provide example code to clarify exactly what you are talking about.

Comment: A float does not have a length (like a string), it has a precision. Also, what is the final goal you want to archive?

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you want to achieve. Why do you need the length of `float` object? Have you tried finding the solution with the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/decimal.html) library?

Comment: also note there are all kinds of problems with floating point precision that you will have to make compromises for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store your values as strings if you want to track length independent of the value of the float.

Floating point values have no length, and trailing 0s do not affect the value so they produce identical floats. This means after it gets defined, there is **no** way to determine whether `0.12345` was defined using `0.12345` or `0.12345000000`.

```
0.12345 is 0.123450  # True
0.12345 is 0.1234500 # True
len(0.12345) # TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

Everything works fine for the string representation of those floats:

```
"0.12345" is "0.123450"    # False
"0.12345" is "0.1234500"   # False
len("0.12345")             # 7
```

Thus you should store these values as strings, and convert them to `float` when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you first convert the input to a number, and then to a string, you'll lose any insignificant digits.

If you are asking the user to enter the value:

```
>>> foo = input('Enter the number here: ')
Enter the number here: 0.0013790
>>> len(foo)
9
```

*If you are using Python 2, make sure you use `raw_input` and not `input`*

As long as you don't cast the value to a float, you should get correct values for `len()`.

Answer (score -1):

Then we have to store the float as a string value. Following lines may be answer to the question where it is a default behaviour.

```
mynum = input('Enter your number: ')
print('Hello', mynum)
print(len(mynum))
```

Comment: your idea of storing as a string is a valid solution, but your code example is not very helpful. Why are you storing a float in a variable called `person`?

Comment: Defauly type of mynum (before editing 'person') is string. So this has all the characters input by the user. Len of the input can be obtained before converting it into float for further processing. Hope I am clear. Best Regards,

Comment: thanks, the variable naming was my main complaint- makes more sense now